# NACL setup to a private subnet connected to internet via nat gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Do we need to open NACL for private subnet  from both inbound and outbound, to the internet when my subnet is routed to NATgateway to access internet .
If yes how secured it is . 
The only restrictions for private subnet  would be on the route table as NACL +security grp will be open .